# Is there any alternative to Remote-Debugging-Server (like Weinre)

Tags: remote-debugging, devtools

I am looking for a more modern Weinre alternative

- Weinre has been without support **for about 3 years**
- Weinre allows me to generate a local server (Example: http://192.168.0.1:8888) exclusive to remotely debug

  - There are many good alternatives like [devtool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/devtool) but... they don't allow you to mount a local server

[image: Weinre]

The reason why I am looking for a remote debugging system is because I want to be able to debug from one Tablet to another tablet, the first tablet that runs the "devtools" from a URL and the second with my page to debug

Tools like Chrome USB debugging only works from a PC plugged into a phone, but not from a phone to another phone over the internet

Do you know any package that allows me to create a devtools server?

Answer (score 0):

[iOS WebKit debug proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy#installation) is a great modern alternative.

It allows you to debug directly in Chrome with live preview.